# Why the year is returned as NaN?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to validate a date and the rules are as follow:

- non leap years or invalid dates
- the year must be greater than 1868

I am using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com) for such validation and this is how I am doing it:

```js
function validate() {
  var value = moment('33/33/1986', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
  var year = moment('33/33/1986', 'MM/DD/YYYY').year();

  console.log(value)
  console.log(year)

  if (value.isValid() && year >= 1868) {
    return true;
  }
}
validate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

Why `year` contains a `NaN` value? Yes I know the date is invalid and `moment().isValid()` will return `false` but even though is not suppose that I should get the proper `year` value?

> Note: The snippet does not print the momentjs object stored in `value`
>   use [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/xpvt214o/557489/) instead.

If by any chance you know a better way to do the same validation feel free to post it here!

Comment: A `return` statement need a `function`

Comment: No, you should not get the year if the date is not valid; that's not how it works.

Comment: Because there was no 33rd day of the 32nd month in 1986.

Comment: I was alive in 1986, and I can tell you, there was no 33rd month or day in that year.

Comment: You don't have a valid date. So you cannot parse the year

Comment: The methods that would be available to a valid date are not available to an invalid date such as `moment('33/33/1986', 'MM/DD/YYYY').year();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Why year contains a NaN value?**

Beacuse `moment('33/33/1986', 'MM/DD/YYYY').isValid()` is `false`, moment [Validation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/) section of the docs explicitly states:

> If a moment is invalid, it behaves like a NaN in floating point operations.
>
> ...
>
> And these return null or NaN with some structure:
>
> - `invalid.get(unit)` returns null, as all other named getters

- **If by any chance you know a better way to do the same validation feel free to post it here!**

You can improve your validation using [strict mode](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/strict-mode/) (adding `true` as third parameter when parsing input), as you can see in the following snippet:

```js
function validate(input) {
  var value = moment(input, 'MM/DD/YYYY', true);
  var year = value.year();

  if (value.isValid() && year >= 1868) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
console.log( validate('33/33/1986') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

Please note that you can use [`isLeapYear()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-leap-year/) function that:

> `moment#isLeapYear` returns `true` if that year is a leap year, and `false` if it is not.

if you have to exclude *non leap years* as you stated in the first part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

`33/33/1986` is not a momentjs valid object because day and month are invalid.

You should try with correct day and month  like `12/12/1986`

Answer (score 2):

MomentJS provides [`parsingFlags`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/) on any call to `moment()` that provides a format. You could use that to try and guess what the year is.

The `parsingFlags` contains a `parsedDateParts` array that contains the values parsed in descending order, with the first value being the year, the second the month, etc.

Obviously, if someone enters an invalid year, then all bets are off...

The below code shows all of the `parsingFlags`, then outputs the year found in the `parsedDateParts`.

```js
function validate() {
  var value = moment('33/33/1986', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
  var year = moment('33/33/1986', 'MM/DD/YYYY').parsingFlags().parsedDateParts[0];

  console.log(moment('33/33/1986', 'MM/DD/YYYY').parsingFlags())
  console.log(year)

  if (value.isValid() && year >= 1868) {
    return true;
  }
}
validate();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: +1 because I strongly think that this was the best answer (except mine :P). `parsingFlags().parsedDateParts[0]` is a good workaround to try to get year of an invalid moment. I was not alive in 1986 but I learned that _there was no 33rd day of the 32nd month_ :D

Answer (score 0):

You cannot parse a non-existing date. There is neither a 33rd day nor a 33rd month. If you use a valid date, your code will run just fine.

Answer (score 0):

First `moment` does not like to parse dates for you without specified format, and it does not like at all parsing bad dates (we have only 12 months and max 31 days so what is `33/33/`?).

try this:

```js
var year = moment('12/20/1986', 'MM/DD/YYYY').year();

if (year >= 1868) {
  console.log('YAY!')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your code is equivalent to `new Date('12/20/1986').getFullYear()`, that may have different output for each browser (see [here](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html)), I suggest to use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) to parse input like `'12/20/1986'`.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks. Updated.